# Big O Notation - O(nlog(n)) vs O(log(n^2))

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Is the notation of NLog(N) the same as Log(N^2)? If so, why is it not written like that?

Is NLog(N) the standard notation? I feel like Log(N^2) is less confusing to see.

Comment: `log (x^2)` is mathematically `2 logx`, and you remove constants. `n log n` is certainly different to that.

Comment: Why do you think the functions are the same? Even if you can't manipulate them algebraically, plotting the functions will show immediately that they're different. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx+log+x,+y%3Dlog(x%5E2),+x%3D1+to+1000

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- **`O(log(n^2))`** is simply `O(2 log(n)) = O(log(n))`. It is a logarithmic function. Its value is **much smaller** than the linear function `O(n)`.
- **`O(n log(n))`** is a larger function. Its values are **larger** than the linear function `O(n)`

They are **completely different** functions (and different big-O complexities). `O(n log(n))` is much larger than `O(log(n^2))`

This plot shows the difference:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Adding logarithms is the same as multiplying numbers, so log(n*n) becomes log(n) + log(n) = 2 log(n).

n log(n) is close to linear. The first n is the important part, as the rest of it grows rather slowly.

For example merge sort has n log n time complexity, because if you think of the merging as a tree, then the tree is log(n) levels tall, and on each level all n elements are processed.

Comment: Does this mean that Nlog(N) = 2log(N)?

Comment: @Nawlidge No. log(N^2) = 2log(N) and O(2log(N)) = O(log(N)). Nlog(N) is completely different. For example log10(100) = 2, but 100*log10(100) is 200.

Answer (score 0):

Nlog(N) = log(N^N) so no and as pointed out by zerkms  above log(N^2) = 2log(N)